# How to set the default date on date box in jQuery mobile with DateBox plugin?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am implementing the date box in jQuery mobile. I am using the date box in pop up, which is working. I need to set the default date (current date) in the text field when a user opens the pop up screen, using (+) button.

http://jsfiddle.net/ravi1989/uhdYv/

```
  <div data-role="popup" id="CaseInformationScreen" data-close-btn="none"  data-overlay-theme="a" data-dismissible="false">
                <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" >

                    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-corners="false" id="Cancel">Cancel</a>
                    <h1>Case Information</h1>
                    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-corners="false" id="AddButton">Add</a>
                </div>

                <div data-role="content">
                    <div><img src="img/Documents.png"/></div>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="text-12" style="text-align:top;margin-left: 0px;">Case Name:</label>
                        <input name="text-12" id="text-12" value="" type="text" class="caseName_h" >
                    </div>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="text-12" style="text-align:left;margin-left: 0px;" >Case Date:</label>
                        <!--input name="text-12" id="text-12" value="" type="date" class="caseDate_h"  -->
                           <input name="mydate" id="mydate" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "datebox", "useNewStyle":true,"zindex":1200}'/>
                    </div>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="textarea-12">Textarea:</label>
                        <textarea cols="40" rows="8" name="textarea-12" id="text-12" class="caseTextArea_h"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: `data-role="datebox"` this is not a standard JQM input type. Are you using a date box plugin for that? If so - give us a name of it.

Comment: for reference, I think I'm the only person who used "datebox" - jQM-DateBox, http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    To set the Text box's value to current date when the popup opens use this code:

    1. Change id of the associated label to myDate:

    <label for="myDate" style="text-align:left;margin-left: 0px;" >Case Date:</label>

    <input name="mydate" id="mydate" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "datebox", "useNewStyle":true,"zindex":1200}'/>

    2. JQM code:

    $( "#CaseInformationScreen" ).bind({
       popupafteropen: function(event, ui) { 
                var date = new Date();

                $('#mydate').trigger('datebox', {
                    'method': 'set',
                    'value': date
                }).trigger('datebox', {
                    'method': 'doset'
                });


       }
    });
```

Comment: You could also set the "defaultValue" property.

Comment: Or, you could just set the value of the input - but you must exactly match the output format datebox is set to use.

Comment: Just setting the default Value will only set the date box value and not the text box field value. why would you take pains to call new Date and set it in text box and then match the format? would it not be extra code and two places to manage, its simple whenever tomorrow date box options or format changes then automatically we derive the exact value from the date box and set it in the text box...in fact most of the cases the text box should be read only in such cases, so that whatever date is selected is only through datebox...

Comment: Absolutely true.  For what it is worth, there is also the "useImmediate" property, which will push "defaultValue" (or the current date if not set) into the input when datebox first initializes.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using regular jQuery.

Try this

```
 $('#dateElement').datepicker('setDate', new Date());
```

**Update**:

Sounds like you're using DateBox plugin. In that case add `"defaultValue", "[2013,1,1]"` in your `data-options`. It takes an array or a string value.

```
<input name="mydate" id="mydate" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"defaultValue", "[2013,1,1]", "mode": "datebox", "useNewStyle":true,"zindex":1200}'/>
```

If you want current date, use it like this.

```
var currentDate = new Date();

"defaultValue", "[" + currentDate.getFullYear() + "," + currentDate.getMonth() + "," + currentDate.getDate() + "]"
```

Comment: but i need the current date.. Not "[2013,1,1]" like 17/7/2013

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [DateBox](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox2/demos/fullopt.html) plugin, the following should work:

```
<input name="mydate" id="mydate" type="date" data-role="datebox" 
       data-options='{"defaultValue": [2013,7,10]}'>
```

Answer (score 0):

These two lines should work:

```
var defaultValue = [year, month, day];
$(element).datebox({'defaultValue' : defaultValue});
```