# jQuery mobile datepicker set value

Tags: jquery-mobile, datepicker

I don't get the jQuery mobile datepicker showing a date.
This is the relevant jsp code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href=<c:url value='/resources/css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css' /> />
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href=<c:url value='/resources/css/jquery.mobile.datepicker.css' /> />
<link rel="stylesheet" href=<c:url value='/resources/css/custom.css' /> />
<script src=<c:url value='/resources/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js' />></script>
<script src=<c:url value='/resources/js/moment-with-locales.min.js' />></script>
<script src=<c:url value='/resources/js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js' />></script>
<script src=<c:url value='/resources/js/jquery.mobile.datepicker.js' />></script>
...
<input class="datepicker" type="date" data-role="datebox" />
...
```

This is the javascript code to set the date:

```
var datepicker = $("#templates .datepicker").clone();
datepicker.attr("id", "birthday");
datepicker.attr("name", "birthday");

...
viewElement.append(datepicker)
...
```

I tried many alternatives, none was showing the date:

```
$("#birthday").text("10.10.10");
$("#birthday").val("10.10.10");
$("#birthday").val("10/10/10");
```

The solution suggested in [How to set the default date on date box in jQuery mobile with DateBox plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17716481) has no effect:

```
$("#personEdit").on("pageshow", function() {

    $('#birthday').trigger('datebox', {
        'method': 'set',
        'value': currentPerson.birthdayAsDate()
    }).trigger('datebox', {
        'method': 'doset'
    });

});
```

These threw an exception:

```
var dynamicDate = new Date(2014,3,22,10,11,0,0);
$("#birthday").datebox('setTheDate', dynamicDate);
```

The exception was "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datebox is not a function" even the box itself was rendered.

How can I set a date value to the jquery mobile datepicker widget?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the default date on date box in jQuery mobile with DateBox plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17716481/how-to-set-the-default-date-on-date-box-in-jquery-mobile-with-datebox-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it. 
After including the pageshow event to init the date value, the log showed up the desiered date format.

So this does the trick:

```
$("#personEdit").on("pageshow", function() {
    $("#birthday").val("2017-01-01");
});
```